# How to quiet Python warnings in my script?

Tags: python, grep, pid, sigkill

I want a Python script to `grep` for a particular process, extract its PID, and kill it. Here's what I'm using:

```
def main():
    # Shutdown Tomcat
    shutdownCmd = "sh ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh"
    subprocess.call([shutdownCmd], shell=True)

    # Check for PID
    grepCmd = "ps -aef | grep tomcat"
    grepResults = subprocess.check_output([grepCmd], shell=True)

    # Get PID(s) and kill it/them.
    for i in range(1, len(grepResults), 9):
    pid = grepResults[i]
    killPidCmd = "kill -9 " + pid
    subprocess.call([killPidCmd], shell=True)

    # Exit.
    sys.exit()
```

However, although it does shutdown my process (Apache Tomcat), I get the following "warnings" in the terminal whenever I run it:

```
kill -l [exitstatus]
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Operation not permitted

/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: h
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: v
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: l
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Operation not permitted

/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: i
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: D
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: l
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: i
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: /
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: s
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: r
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: /
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: c
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: t
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: c
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: i
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: r
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: a
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: l
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: a
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: g
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: j
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: s
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: g
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: 
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: X
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: 
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: n
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: i
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: /
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: s
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: r
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: /
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: c
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: t
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: e
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: 
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: h
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: h
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: n
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: /
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: o
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: e
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Operation not permitted

/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: n
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: a
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: o
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: e
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: x
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: c
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: t
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: a
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: m
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Operation not permitted

/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: m
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: .
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: t
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: s
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: z
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: a
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: v
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: t
Killed
```

Can any Python meastros take a look at the script and figure out why I'm getting all these `/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: <whatever>` warnings/errors/ouputs? Any suggestions as to how to fix them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Randall L. Schwartz would have said, "[useless use of `kill -9`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter)"!

Comment: Please also have a close look at @dbr s solution. His version is how these kind of scripts should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(1, len(grepResults), 9):
    pid = grepResults[i]
    killPidCmd = "kill -9 " + pid
    subprocess.call([killPidCmd], shell=True)
```

Looks like your grepResults is some plain string, and you're picking single characters from it. That's why `kill` complains about strange numbers (which are no numbers but chars) that you're giving to it. Check the output of this command, then you should see, what's going wrong:

```
grepResults = subprocess.check_output([grepCmd], shell=True)
```

Insert something like that and check, if `pid` fits for you. Also make sure, that the criterias (`if 'grep' in line`) fit and don't match other processes. Maybe you have to add more if-clauses here.

```
import subprocess
grepCmd = "ps -aef | grep tomcat"
grepResults = subprocess.check_output([grepCmd], shell=True)
for line in grepResults.strip().split('\n'):
    if 'grep' in line: 
        continue
    pid = line.split()[1]
else:
    pid = None
# print pid
```

If `pid` is `None`, it should exit with error, as there was no running service found. And in case you want to kill more than one `pid`, of course you have to create some list, or directly kill the pid within this loop.

Comment: Thanks @Michael (+1) - I guess that makes sense. Is there a way to rewrite this so I don't have `kill` complaining about these "strange" numbers? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` with `./script.py 2>/dev/null` to get rid of these messages.

Comment: Thanks @Anton Guryanov (+1) - where would I add this (in the script, or as I'm calling the script)? It would be preferable to do this in the Python so I just need to call `python myshutdownscript.py` and get no warning/error messages. Also, can you explain to me what these are, and why I'm seeing them? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't do this. Your script is seriously broken, you better fix it, instead of suppressing the errors!

Comment: @Michael yep, it is broken, but as long as it doesn't do any harm, you can suppress errors. @pnongrata Use `python myshutdownscript.py 2>/dev/null`, but don't do that in general case, as suggested above. Also you may consider using bash scripts, it seems more suitable in your case.

Comment: Well, it's blindly trying to kill processes. If there are actually numbers in the string, it will start to kill these processes. And as a matter of fact, in the parsed string there _are_ numbers, so it tries to kill processes 0-9 regularly. If you have a long running server, theses PIDs are sooner or later being reused, and then this script kicks in and kills them with SIGTERM. That's at least not what I understand as good practice of server administration ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are treating the grep output like a list, when it's actually a string.. Change your line:

```
killPidCmd = "kill -9 " + pid
```

To:

```
killPidCmd = "echo kill -9 " + pid
```

..and look at the output, and the problem will be clear.

Slightly tweaked version of the script, which doesn't use `shell=True` (which is rarely necessary, and cause cause problems with shell-escaping), does the equivalent to grep in Python,

```
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    # Shutdown Tomcat
    scriptPath = "%s/bin/shutdown.sh" % (os.environ[TOMCAT_HOME])
    shutdownCmd = ["sh", scriptPath]
    subprocess.call(shutdownCmd)

    # Check for PID
    psCmd = ["ps", "-aef"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(psCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    so, se = p.communicate()

    grep = [line for line in so.splitlines() if "python" in line]

    for line in grep:
        pid = line.split()[1] # Second column
        killPidCmd = ["kill", "-9", pid]
        subprocess.call(killPidCmd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Again I'd recommend you change `killPidCmd = ["kill", "-9", pid]` to `killPidCmd = ["echo", "kill", "-9", pid]` to verify everything is working correctly

That said, this would be much simpler as a shell script:

```
${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh

pids=$(ps -aef | grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}')
kill -9 ${pids}
```